# Mudar caracteres de string Javascript para sucessores

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Possuo uma string, por exemplo, **acbd** e quero obter uma outra string **bdce**, formada pelos sucessores de cada caractere.

Em minhas pesquisas encontre uma forma possível que é transformar a string num array e em seguida iterá-lo para obter uma nova string.

```js
var r = "acbd".split("").map(function(a) { 
  return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
}).reduce(function(p, c) {
  return p + c
});

console.log(r);
```

Contudo, estou tentando descobrir um possível algorítimo para mudar os caracteres para seus sucessores, sem transformar a string em um array usando o método `replace` com uma `RegExp`. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui está o código:

```js
var r = "abcd".replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function myFunction(x){
  return String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0)+1);
});
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Blz isso mesmo, vlw